# How to calculate the sum of VLOOKUP with two criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I'm looking for a clean(er) way (than using `SUMIF` with a third row) to calculate the sum of the results from, say, a `VLOOKUP` that checks both the first and the second row for matching criterion.

So, given the Transaction spreadsheet, I'd like to generate the data in the Report spreadsheet - ignoring for the moment how I determine which client/account combinations are relevant in the Report spreadsheet - by adding up the values in Transactions which have the given client and account.

*Transactions*

```
CLIENT         | ACCOUNT        | VALUE
---------------|----------------|----------------
001            | 001            |  25.00
001            | 001            |   5.00
001            | 002            |  10.00
002            | 002            |  23.00
002            | 002            |   6.00
003            | 001            |   5.00
003            | 001            |   1.25
003            | 001            | 204.00
003            | 003            |  14.00
```

*Report*

```
CLIENT         | ACCOUNT        | TOTAL
---------------|----------------|----------------
001            | 001            |  30.00
001            | 002            |  10.00
002            | 002            |  29.00
003            | 001            | 210.25
003            | 003            |  14.00
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The entire report can be generated using the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343?hl=en) function:

`=QUERY(Transactions!A:C,"select A, B, sum(C) group by A, B label sum(C) 'TOTAL'",0)`

Comment: Wait, I can do QUERYs? Well that just made life infinitely easier, many thanks.

Comment: This works great - thanks. Any ideas how I would go about this if my column B (account) was the date and I wanted to group by the month (eg if 01/02/2014) I want to group everything in 02 (Feb). Thanks

Comment: @raison you could create a new column called month where you extract the month from the date with `=month(B15)`. Then group by the month column.

Answer (score 7):

Since this appears to have been viewed rather frequently over the last two years, I thought I'd chime in with an updated answer.

**SUMIFS**

[SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) is my go-to for things like this now. It's [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) with multiple possible criteria. So, for something like this, one would use the following function in `Report!C1` (assuming `Report!1:1` is the first row of data):

```
=SUMIFS(Transactions!$C:$C,Transactions!$A:$A,$A1,Transactions!$B:$B,$B1)
```